# Extracting string based on 2 lists of integers. Python

Tags: python, string, integer, extract

```
seq = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

start = [2,9,18]
end = [6,12,20]

#output = seq[end[k]:start[k+1]]
```

i'm trying to the sequence between end[k] and start[k+1] #seq[end[k]:start[k+1]]

so there should be 2 sequences in this case.

```
outp1 = seq[6:9] #'GHI'

out2 = seq[12:18] #'MNOPQR'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(end)-1):
    seq[end[i]:start[i+1]]

answer:-
    'GHI'
    'MNOPQR'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `zip`:

```
>>> seq = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> start = [2,9,18]
>>> end = [6,12,20]
>>> for x,y in zip(end, start[1:]):
...     print seq[x:y]
...     
GHI
MNOPQR
```

Memory efficient version:

```
>>> from itertools import izip,islice
>>> for x,y in izip(end,islice(start,1,None)):
    print seq[x:y]
...     
GHI
MNOPQR
```